# Waiting for extra digit when it's clear that there's no other matching rule

Tags: asterisk

I'm a beginner on Asterisk, but already have my PBX working connected to the PSTN. The issue I'm having is that I have this rule

```
exten => _*X.*,1,Log(DEBUG, Calling through provider one to ${EXTEN:1:-1})      
  same => n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:1:-1}@oneProvider,60)
```

There are no other extensions that start with *. What I want to achieve is to dial out as soon as the second * is pressed (and there's nothing the user can press to go to a valid extension), right now it waits a few seconds and dial. I also tried adding ! at the end of the extension, but nothing changed.

Am I missing something? Is this feasible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is not doable in current asterisk.
It will not work beacuase * matched .(dot) in your dialplan.

Except dialplan like this(very ugly one beacuase it will go dialplan for every new digit)

```
[originalcontext]
exten => *,1,Goto(collect_number,s,1)

[collect_number]
exten => s,1,WaitExten(); wait for single digit

exten => *,1,Set(stars=${stars}*);save stars
exten => *,2,GotoIF($[ "${stars}" == "**" ]?dial,1); if 2 star already,go dial.

exten =>_X,1,Set(digits=${digits}${EXTEN});save digits

exten => _.,3,WaitExten(); wait enother input;
exten => _.,4,Goto(dial,1); go dial if no new digits


exten => dial,1,Dial(SIP/${digits}@oneProvider,60)
```

Correct solution - use Read application and ask user use # to end number instead of *.

You also can try dialplan like this:

```
   exten => _*X*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXXXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXXXXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXXXXXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1)
   exten => _*XXXXXXXX*!,1,Goto(dial,${EXTEN:1:-1},1); continue upto max number length

   [dial]
    exten =>_.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@oneProvider,,);
```

But i not fully sure that will work. If works, will be less load(but more lines)

Comment: Thanks! Most importantly, you helped me understand why it didn't work... I thought . worked as in regular expressions (where it means any amount of the previous symbol) while in Asterisk it actually means anything any amount of times.

Comment: Nop. It much simpler then regular expressions. It is patern-matching, check this http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Patterns

Comment: I read that page like a thousand times... but I was already biased :) thanks!

Comment: Maybe that because you know about regexp. That page writed for people who know nothing and want "run it right now"